# AWS Linux Timezone Changes in Server

Tags: php, datetime, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have an AWS Linux Machine with the following version:

```
Linux version 3.13.0-74-generic (buildd@lcy01-07) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015
```

The server uptime was since more than 100 days. When I tried to check the `date`, it shows me:

```
Fri Jan  5 19:07:06 UTC 2018
```

... currently.

However, once in a while, I see that it changes from UTC to PST.

I'm using PHP and the dates are saved on the servers using seconds epoch time. So, it messes up the system.

Is there anyway to make it stay? What cause the changes? How should I fix it?

(I'm also wondering if PHP can change the server default time).

Thoughts or answers please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have idea what could cause the change but you can fix it.

You can [set the default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php) used by all php date/time functions with the following line in your `php.ini` file:

`date.timezone = "UTC"`

You can change your server's default timezone to UTC executing the following command:

`sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC` ([see an answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323131/setting-timezone-from-terminal/524362#524362))

or

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` ([see an answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138423/how-do-i-change-my-timezone-to-utc-gmt#138442) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110522/timezone-setting-in-linux#110529)) and follow the instructions.

Also using the `date` command you can get date and time in ***UTC*** using the `-u` or the `--utc` flags or you can call `TZ=UTC date`.